# Which cert bundle does httpi is using

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, savon, httpi

I am wondering which certificates bundle does [httpi](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpi/2.3.0) is using?

I am using centOS 5 that has ca-bundle.crt under /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

It seems that openSSL is using the above ca-bundle but httpi is not ?

Comment: httpi is just a standard wrapper for other HTTP clients. which are you using underneath httpi? http://httpirb.com/#adapters

Comment: I am using httpclient 2.1.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Client has their own certificates bundled into it. See [Issue #187](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient/pull/187).

This can be set using `http_client.ssl_config.set_default_paths` to use the system certificates

Answer (score 0):

httpi is only a wrapper around a locally installed http client package. It uses whatever this underlying package is using.